# how to call object dynamically in jButton action?

Tags: java, swing, object, jbutton

i want to do something like this

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
        int i = 0;

        NewClass[] obj = new NewClass[i];

        obj[i] = new  NewClass(args..);

         i++;
}
```

every time the button clicks, it creates a new object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, place

```
int i = 0;
NewClass[] obj;
```

outside the method.

Secondly, why use an Array and not a Collection? It would then be simply:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  //somewhere outside: List<NewClass> obj = new ArrayList<>();
  obj.add(new NewClass(args..);
}
```